# How to link our app to the app present in android market

Tags: android, google-play

I have created an app which is a paid version. I recently launched my paid version of the app in the android market.

Now I have created the free version of that app, which is also launched in the android market. There is a button in my free version app. So when I click that button I want to open a link of the android market where my paid version of the app is. I mean to say that I have an option in my free app from which I can get the paid version of my app which is stored in the android market.

So can anyone please help me to solve this out?

Regards
Anshuman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to raise a special kind of intent on button click. Refer to [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent) for details.

Answer (score 4):

i found this in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.android.example"));
startActivity(intent);
```